# Cutting bars problem with integer programming.

Tags: integer-programming

How to model the Linear Programming for the problem below with the most complete + reasonable constraints.
A production facility has 2 types of reinforcement bars 6m, 8m long (unlimited quantity). Need to process 100 2.4m and 150 2.8m sections. Ask how to cut rebar to save the most?
This is a practice homework in my school. It bother me for a while. I don't know how to set variables. I set number of 2.4m bar, 2.8m bar in 6m bar is x, y; 2.4m bar, 2.8m bar in 8m bar is a, b; then number of 6m, 8m bar is n1, n2. Then one of constraints is $n_1x+n_2a\leq100$. That is non-linear so I can't continue solving with integer programming. Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can we cut the bars to 2.4 and 2.8 pieces? Let $x_i$ and $y_i$ be the different cuts as follows

$$\begin{aligned}
x_1 &: 6 = 2.4+2.4+\color{red}{1.2} \\
x_2 &: 6 = 2.4+2.8+\color{red}{0.8} \\
x_3 &: 6 = 2.8+2.8+\color{red}{0.4} \\
y_1 &: 8 = 2.4+2.4+2.4+\color{red}{0.8} \\
y_2 &: 8 = 2.4+2.4+2.8+\color{red}{0.4} \\
y_3 &: 8 = 2.4+2.8+2.8 \\
\end{aligned}$$

So we should minimize the number of bars used.

\begin{align}
\min \quad& z=  x_1+x_2+x_3+y_1+y_2+y_3 \label{z1} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad& 2x_1+x_2+3y_1+2y_2+y_2 \ge 100 \tag{1}\label{c1} \\
& x_2+2x_3+y_2+2y_3 \ge 150 \tag{2}\label{c2} \\
& x_i, y_j \geq 0 \space \text{(int)}. \tag{3}\label{c3}
\end{align}

Comment: I think $min\quad z=1.2x_1+0.8x_2+0.4x_3+0.8y_1+0.4y_2$ right?

Comment: @BùiTrườngGiang If you want minimize the number of bars used you should $min(\sum{x_i} +\sum{y_i})$ but if you want to minimize wasted pieces yes you rigth.